# How to write table vertically in python docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am exporting data to Word Docx I am getting a result like this

[image]

with this code

```
records = Model.objects.filter(pk=pk)

table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)

hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
hdr_cells[0].text = 'data1'
hdr_cells[1].text = 'data2'
hdr_cells[2].text = 'data3'

for record in records:
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    row_cells[0].text = record.data1
    row_cells[1].text = record.data2
    row_cells[2].text = record.data3
```

but I am want to have it like this

[image]

I have tried a number of ways but every time I am getting an error and I might have more than 3 data if I add `hdr_cells[3]` it throws the `index out of range` error. please can anyone help on this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to extract a function. You'll also need to form the dimensions of the table from the query result:

```
def write_column(col, record):
    cells = column.cells
    for i, field in record:
        cells[i].text = field

records = Model.objects.filter(pk=pk)
table = document.add_table(rows=len(records[0]), cols=len(records))
for i, record in enumerate(records):
    write_column(table.columns[i], record)
```

You haven't specified the type of the `record` object, so I've assumed list here. You might need some adjustments depending on the specifics.

If record fields are only available by attribute name (like `.data1`, `.data2`, etc.), you'll need to include or get schema information to make that mapping, which could affect how flexible this code is to schema changes (like being used for more than one record type).